# Can't connect to shared hosting database with site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

Slightly at my wits end.  Built an application, running fine locally.  Migrated my database to MSSQL without issue, uploaded the site, can't seem to get the application to connect to the database.  Any page that accesses the database I get a generic error message.

I've tried all the separate combinations of connection strings I could think of using the Godaddy recommended connection strings.  Perhaps I am overlooking something simple?

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First -- My context model is called CombosContext.

```
<add name="CombosContext" connectionString=" Server=jelatin.db.9508732.hostedresource.com; Database=jelatin; User ID=jelatin; Password=********; Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString=" Server=jelatin.db.9508732.hostedresource.com; Database=jelatin; User ID=jelatin; Password=********; Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Server**: jelatin.db.9508732.hostedresource.com

**DB name**: jelatin

**user**: jelatin

**Table**: Comboes

Comment: Can you connect w/ SQL Management Studio? Also, what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: And as to the SSMS, I didn't select the "allow direct access" when setting the DB up, but I will turn it on now and test with SSMS.

Comment: See [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/), or [sql server 2008 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) specifically. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with GoDaddy hosted SQL, but usually a connection string to MS SQL Server uses "Data Source" instead of "Server" and "Initial Catalog" instead of "Database".

UPDATE

I didn't realize Server and Database were allowed options in the Connection String.  Sorry for the confusion.

Regarding the database itself - are you letting EF create the database?  Does the user have permission on GoDaddy's system to create a database?

If you have already created the database, did you populate anything?  I have found that EF Code First won't correctly populate the database if the database exists and the metadata table doesn't.  If you can, try copying your local database up to GoDaddy, and see if the connection works.

Finally, for your generic error message - is it coming back in a 500 error?  If so, have you tried using either IE or Chrome's dev tools to inspect the response?  Better error information is usually hidden in there.

Comment: In answer to your earlier question, I can connect to the database with SSMS and see the table.

Comment: In the end it was some stupid box you have to check in GoDaddy to allow direct connections.  This breakdown was illuminated after I attempted your recommendation of connecting with SSMS and saw that it was failing.

Thanks for the help!